# Sharepoint: Redirect user to default site

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to set a default site for a group of users in Sharepoint and have the main default page redirect them to the sub site?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know an out of the box feature which could do this, but you could write a small WebPart which does the redirect depending on the user who visits the site. Shouldn't be to difficult.

The configuration could either be stored in the web part itself or within a list. To speedup the whole redirect process you should cache the redirect information when it was read from the configuration.

That's the way I would do this.

Don't forget to think about a way which let you access and edit the page with the redirect web part without getting redirected.